# how to configure tapestry module to autoload

Tags: config, tapestry, autoload

Where is the [pom.xml](http://tapestry.apache.org/component-libraries.html) on step 5? How to configure the module to autoload?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: As per the tutorial, it is assumed that you have *Maven2* as build tool!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There has been a problem  with the site (related to displaying code snippets) after an upgrade. If you are not able to view pom.xml in step 5, here it is

```
<plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
       <configuration>
       <archive>
         <manifestEntries>
         <Tapestry-Module-Classes>org.example.happylib.services.HappyModule</Tapestry-Module-Classes>
         </manifestEntries>
       </archive>
       </configuration>
   </plugin>
```